# Copy the last non empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a code that I need to always copy the lat NON empty cell of column C in the spreadsheet called "Support2". Then I need to paste in the spreadsheet "Final", always on the cell A2. So I will update the spreadsheet everyday and more values will be added on Column C, that's why it needs to copy always the last one. I have tried the code below but it is not working. I would appreciate your help, Thanks!

Sub test()

```
Dim myLastCell As Range
Set myLastCell = LastCell(Worksheets("Support2").Range("C:C"))
    End Sub


    ' Now Copy the range:
    Worksheets("Support2").Range("C:c" & myLastCell.Row).Copy

Else
    MsgBox ("There is no data in specified range")
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: There's an `End Sub` in the middle of your code. Did you even bother trying to compile or run it?

Answer (score 0):

Needed another Sheet("Support2) in it

```
Sub test()

Sheets("Support2").Range("C" & Sheets("Support2").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
Sheets("Final").Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks, it runs but it is not copying the right value. Your code gets the value on cell C1, and I need the last Non empty cell, which would be the c87

Comment: When you say the last non-empty cell. I'm assuming range(C1:C86) is populated?

Comment: Thats correct. Today C1:C87 is populated, tomorrow C1:C88 will be, so today i need C87, tomorrow C88...

Comment: I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work then. I've just tested it with a third sheet being active and it still worked... Are you inserting this into a module?

Comment: I am doing the VBA in "ThisWorkbook". I think the problem is the Range("C1"), because i dont need to copy C1, i need the last cell in column C. Do you know any other way to write that?

Comment: You could do....
'Sheets("Support2").Range("C" & Sheets("Support2").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Copy'